# Excel Web Access

Tags: 2007

Getting this error when i try and open an excel spread sheet as a web page: 'Excel Web Access: An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator if this problem persists'

two questions:

1. what is the relation between excel calculation services and excel services? and
2. should excel calculation services be running on farm for excel web access to work, even if all i want is to display spread sheets and not do any calculations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Excel Calculation Services (ECS) to run Excel Web Access (EWA). See ECS as the backend of EWA.